# A Weird One involving IIS and Windows Authentication with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

We have an ASP.net app running on a pair of hosted servers. Access to the app is controlled by IIS using integrated Windows security. ASP code files are in one iis site while static content is served from another. The files sit on a UNC share `\\10.x.x.1\mySites` and are accessed by users running IE8 and 9.

In the last fortnight or so, the application users are finding it difficult to access the site. Now, when they request the URI they get presented with the standard login box which reappears after every single attempt at gaining access. After a half a dozen attempts the process ends with a '401 Not Authorized' error.

This is odd enough, but after getting one of our network guys to take a look at it, it turns out that the credentials the user typed into the IIS password prompt are not being transmitted to IIS - rather its the credentials (Windows login Id & password) of the current user that are.

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think IIS holds user account credentials separately in order that it can proces anon access. If this gets out of sync with the corresponding system credentials for the anonymous account, this sort of thing can happen. Have a poke around, I think there is a way to reset IIS.